# Is there a noop command in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I have a [aliased](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_aliases) command that I'm using to generate an [xrefitem](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem) page in my doxygen configuration.

```
ALIASES += "satisfy{2}=\xrefitem satisfy \"Satisfies\" \"Bottom up traceability\" requirement \1 in section: \ref \2"
```

If I want a second configuration that does not generate this page, and take out that alias I'm going to get a warning:

```
Warning: Found unknown command `\satisfy'
```

Is there a different alias I could enter that makes an essentially noop command?

I tried:

```
ALIASES += "satisfy{2}= \ref \2 Satisfies requirement \1
```

And:

```
ALIASES += "satisfy{2}= Satisfies requirement
```

But this resulted in the output just echoing the arguments.

```
{1114,intro1}
```

Any suggestions?  Looking at the documentation for [ALIASES](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_aliases), I'm not even sure how the original alias parameters work, the `\1`, `\2` syntax isn't documented there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the syntax wrong.  Note the missing close quotes in the samples in my question.

Noop:

```
ALIASES +=    "satisfy{2}="
```

If you want plain text output:

```
ALIASES +=    "satisfy{2}=\2 satisfies \1"
```

Comment: `"satisfy{2} = \ref \2 Satisfies requirement \1"` also works.

Comment: So I was right to doubt the missing trailing quote after all. Interestingly, the manual puts the quotes where I put them, which is different to where you have them (whether or not to encompass the `satisfy{2}=` )

Comment: The quotes around the whole thing are generated by Doxywizard.

Comment: Sorry I missed that you'd included the bit about the typo.  I went straight to your examples and tested them...

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear I'm understanding the question.  You have in your code text like
`\satisfy Foo Bah`. In the configuration without the xrefitem, you are still parsing the text but don't have the alias defined?

I believe you can have overloaded aliases, so does defining the following (with no parameters) help?

`ALIASES += satisfy="Satisfies"`

...but I'm unsure what you want to happen with the parameters in the non-cross-referenced case.

Alternatively, as written, I think you may have a typo (location of ") in the syntax of your later ALIAS definitions.  I'd have expected:

`ALIASES += satisfy{2}="\ref \2 Satisfies requirement \1"`

Another alternative might be to define a NOOP with another alias:

`ALIASES += noop{1}="\cond \1 \endcond"`

or simply

`ALIASES += satisfy{2}="\cond \2 \1 \endcond"`

Comment: satisfy="Satisfies" gets rid of the warning, but still prints out "{1114,intro1}" in the output.  Ideally it would print nothing, but alternatively I'll take a sentence form like "intro1 satisfies 1114".

Comment: `satisfy{2}="\cond \2 \1 \endcond"` may be on the right track.  It prints out `"*//*"`  I also tried `satisfy{2}="\cond FALSE \2 \1 \endcond"` and got the same results.

Comment: FYI, the documentation I could not find earlier on arguments:  http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/custcmd.html#custcmd_complex